# Countdown timer in JavaScript not stopping

Tags: javascript, html, css, timer

I have a timer that counts down from 5:00 minutes, but it does not stop! It just goes into the negative. 
HTML

```
<p>Click the button to begin the quiz. Good Luck!</p>
            <button id="start" class="button">Start</button>    
            <div class="timer">
                Timer: <span id="time"> 5:00 </span> minutes
            </div>
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 05 + ":" + 00;

function startTimer() {
    var p_time = document.getElementById('time').innerHTML;
    var timeArray = p_time.split(/[:]+/);
    var min = timeArray[0];
    var sec = checkSecond((timeArray[1]-1));
    if(sec==59){min=min-1}
    if(min <= 0 && sec == 0) {alert("Time is up!")}

    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
    setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
}

function checkSecond(seconds) {
    if(seconds <10 && seconds >= 0) {seconds ="0" + seconds};
    if(seconds <0) {seconds = "59"};
    return seconds;
}
```

CSS

```
.timer {
    color: var(--primary);
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

I have the JS saying that when minutes is less than or equal to 0 AND seconds equal 0, then alert "time is up". So I get the popup alert, but once I click "ok" on the popup, the timer keeps counting down into negative. 
Also, in the picture, the "5:00" isn't showing up - it only shows one zero. 
[image]

Comment: After the `alert()` happens, what would prevent the subsequent call to `setTimeout()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove the timer by using `clearTimeout` once the timer completes 5 minutes.

check this if stackoverflow snippets isn't working - https://jsfiddle.net/e5v80xmk/

```js
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = 05 + ":" + 00;
document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', startTimer);

var timerRef = null;

function startTimer() {
  var p_time = document.getElementById('time').innerHTML;
  var timeArray = p_time.split(/[:]+/);
  var min = timeArray[0];
  var sec = checkSecond((timeArray[1] - 1));
  if (sec == 59) {
    min = min - 1
  }

  document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;

  if (min <= 0 && sec == 0) {
    clearTimeout(timerRef)
    alert("Time is up!")
    return
  }


  timerRef = setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
}

function checkSecond(seconds) {
  if (seconds < 10 && seconds >= 0) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds
  };
  if (seconds < 0) {
    seconds = "59"
  };
  return seconds;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to begin the quiz. Good Luck!</p>
<button id="start" class="button">Start</button>
<div class="timer">
  Timer: <span id="time"> 5:00 </span> minutes
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to *tell it to stop*. E.g. by returning if the time is up. Something like

```
if(min <= 0 && sec == 0) {return alert("Time is up!")}
//                        ^ now the next statements won't run
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
setTimeout(startTimer, 1000);
```